# Accessing local Firebase Environment Variables when running Node test.js locally

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have the following simple `test.js`:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
console.log(functions.config().supportgmail.email);
```

I've done the following before running `node test.js`:

1. `firebase functions:config:get > .runtimeconfig.json`
2. `firebase emulators:start`
3. `node test.js`

After running `node test.js`, I get the following error and the environment variable wasn't output to the console:

```
{"severity":"WARNING","message":"Warning, FIREBASE_CONFIG and GCLOUD_PROJECT environment variables are missing. 
Initializing firebase-admin will fail"}
```

What else do I need to do in `test.js` in order to make the local Firebase environment variables accessible? Note that when I run the entire web app project locally, it has no problem accessing the local environment variables except when I run a JS independently using `node test.js` -- I just want to make my newly created function that needs to access the environment variables works before incorporate it into my app project. Thanks!

Comment: What runtime are you using? What does engines field of your package.json say?
Could you also please shared the version of firebase-tools you are using? Run firebase --version. Please share your runtimeconfig.json file.

Comment: After starting my emulator, it says `Your requested "node" version "10" doesn't match your global version "12"`, so I presume I'm using version 12 of Node.js. My firebase-tools version is `8.16.2` currently. Sorry, I can't share my `runtimeconfig.json`, it contains security information.

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs when functions are deployed with Node v10 ( Please let me know if you are not using Node 10 ). It is caused by a bug in firebase-functions. The Node 10 environment does not include GCLOUD_PROJECT anymore. As a workaround, you can add the following line to your code:

```
process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT = JSON.parse(process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG).projectId
```

or you can downgrade to Node 8 until this issue is fixed.

Also please try to redeploy the Cloud Function.

Please also have a look into the following GitHub threads regarding this issue [1](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/437), [2](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/630#issuecomment-600259931).

************ UPDATE **************

As per the following message:

***Your requested "node" version "10" doesn't match your global version "12"***, the message is not an error if not it's just letting you know that your package.json declares a target node version of 10, but you are using node 12 on your machine for emulation. To get rid of the message, please install node 10 instead of 12 on your machine. Or vice-versa.

Please make sure which [Node.js version are you using in your package.json file](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_nodejs_version) in the **engines** field.

As per [Firebase Official Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_nodejs_version), it is stated that

```
Firebase SDK for Cloud Functions 2.0.0 and higher allows a selection of Node.js runtime
```

and as you are using Node.js, your Cloud Functions SDK should be 2.0.0 or higher, so please follow the next steps or have a look into the [Official Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff) to make sure you have the correct SDK installed:

1. Update SDKs to the latest version if you haven't done it, run the following in the functions folder:

npm install firebase-functions@latest --save
npm install firebase-admin@latest --save-exact

2. Also update Firebase CLI to the latest version:

npm install -g firebase-tools

If you want your local emluation of functions using firebase serve to pick up environment variables, you need to follow the next [Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator).

> If you're using custom functions configuration variables, run the
> following command in the functions directory of your project before
> running firebase serve.
>
> `firebase functions:config:get > .runtimeconfig.json`
>
> However, if you're using Windows PowerShell, replace the above command with:
>
> `firebase functions:config:get | ac .runtimeconfig.json`

And lastly the main point which is missing and stated stated in the [Cloud Functions Official Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env#automatically_populated_environment_variables) is that this **configuration is applied automatically when you initialize the Firebase Admin SDK with no arguments**.
Please add the following:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

let firebaseConfig = JSON.parse(process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG);
let project = firebaseConfig.projectId;
console.log(project);
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: I tried to add `process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT = JSON.parse(process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG).projectId` in my `test.js`, but seems like the `process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG` is also undefined even during the emulator is running: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)`.

Comment: It works when I hardcoded `process.env["GCLOUD_PROJECT"] = "my-project-id";`. Apparently, the `process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG` is still missing while running the independent `test.js`.

Comment: I updated the answer, let me know if after performing the previous steps, you still get the same issue.

Comment: Nope, I've done all the above as you told, including updating the `firebase-functions` and `firebase-admin` to the latest version, but still the same: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)`. It's ok, I can wait for the future bug fixed version. Just update your answer when the bug fixed version is out. Thank you.

Comment: Are you setting Firebase Config as following : let firebaseConfig = JSON.parse(process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG); ?

Comment: Yes, this is why that `SyntaxError` appears. Please read my previous comments again.

Comment: I reproduced your issue, however I was not getting any error when getting the firebase Config as above. I tried in both Nodejs 12 and 10. I was getting the Project ID correctly. I updated my answer with the exact code I used.